# Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/rxjs'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added angular material in my project, Im getting this error. I removed my node modules and re-installed too. Even then Im getting this error.

```
Failed to compile.

./~/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/rxjs' in '/home/asus/angular-app/node_modules/@angular/material/esm5'
 @ ./~/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js 16:0-89
 @ ./~/@angular/material/esm5/material.es5.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5454 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: Did you try `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk` ?

Comment: Does your NPM throws an error ? Did you follow the material guide and installed the cdk ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see the changelog (aka [`5.0.0-rc0`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5.0.0-rc0))? That's because they're removing `rxjs` from `@angular/cdk`. You should use `rxjs` instead.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes):

> - `@angular/cdk/rxjs` has been removed in favor of RxJS 5.5's lettable operators.

Comment: I have the same error but I've no idea what I have to do to fix it

Comment: @JoeAllen What I said above: Use `RxJS` which should be installed by default. Change your `rxjs` imports to remove `@angular/cdk`

Comment: @JoeAllen Did you find an answer to this issue. I don't understand what the comment above means? I am using the default 'rxjs' in my import statements anyway, but I still get your error!

Comment: I am using the latest version of Angular 4, the latest version of RxJs, and the latest versions of Material/CDK etc. I get hundreds of errors when trying to compile. All of them point to a problem between Material & RxJs: Here is one example: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js Module not found

Comment: "@angular/cli": "1.5.0","rxjs": "5.4.2","@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5","@angular/material": "^5.2.5"...OK. So the latset version of the CLI is 1.7.4, but I am not far off. It seem to have the wrong path, because it is looking in directories that do not exist, like: ...\unit-test\rxjs-chat\src\rxjs\operators\tap.js doesn't exist as directory. It should be something more like: ...\unit-test\rxjs-chat\node_modules\rxjs. But I don't even have an 'operators' directory. I only have 'operator' directory and also there is no 'tap.js' etc. What a mess?

Comment: @Edric I think I may need to update RxJS to 5.5.10, because I can see, in this newer version, the directories that my errors are pointing to, like 'operators' & also the file 'tap.js' now exists in the newer version. I am a bit worried about just installing version 5.5.10 over my existing version of 5.4.2? Is it safe to install over the top, or do I need to uninstall the previous version of RxJS? Thanks, in advance, for any help you can provide me...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error. 
The version of "@angular/material" appearing in the dependencies defined in package.json, mismatched the one gotten by running the command:

npm show @angular/material version

It was solved by updating angular material to the latest version by running this command:

npm install @angular/material@latest --save

Check that the installed version matches the one defined in package.json.